# Loading Array of Images

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, image

I have a set of images on a windows form. I want to add an image to an array when a checkbox corresponding to an image is checked.  Everytime I check the box it says "FileNotFoundException was unhandled."

```
public partial class FrmSignage : Form
{
    Image[] images = new Image[12];
    int i = 0;
    public FrmSignage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void chkRadiation_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        images[i] = Image.FromFile("radiation.gif");   
        i++;
    }
```

The error is thrown on the line "images[i] = Image.FromFile("radiation.gif");".  The filename is correct.  What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the path of the file vs the local directory of the running process.

Comment: You can do `MessageBox.Show(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());` to see what directory your app is running from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The filename is correct.

You need to supply the correct path to the file, as well.  It is likely that the filename is correct, but the current directory is not what you expect.

By default, it will try to load the image from the same folder as the .exe - ie: `Project\bin\Debug`, but this can change at runtime.  Loading an image without specifying the path is not safe because the current directory can be changed, so you should specify the full path.

The classes in System.IO, such as [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx), provide quite a bit of functionality for building the proper path.

Comment: I tried to add the full file path, but I get a syntax error saying "Unrecognized escape sequence".  How do I work around that?

Comment: @talbright Either prefix the string with `@`, or use `\\` instead of `\` for the path separators.

Comment: @talbright So you'd do something like `Image.FromFile(@"C:\Path\To\radiation.gif");` or `Image.FromFile("C:\\Path\\To\\radiation.gif")`

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the path "radiation.gif" makes sense. This will always check in the directory in which the executable is running.

Comment: Not "always" but rather "by default".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file is not found relative to the running code.  Even if the file exists in your environment because it is a relative path it must exist relative to the running code.

One way to do this is that assuming you have the image as a project item you can change the build action for it to `Content` and set the copy to output directory as `Copy if Newer` (these options can be found in the Properties window for an item)

You should also add some error handling to your code because what's to stop your users from deleting the image even if you've ensured it is in the right place?